superset deployment on kubernetes
I'm trying to deploy Superset via helm ( superset-0.12.11 ) on onprem kubernetes ( v1.29.8 ) based on procedure https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/kubernetes/. With default settings all went ok, but I would like to deploy it with service type LoadBalancer.
So when I change part of values.yaml:
service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 8088
  annotations: {}
    # cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  loadBalancerIP: ~
  nodePort:
    # -- (int)
    http: nil

with:
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 8088

I'm keep getting following error:
Error: 1 error occurred:
        * Service in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Service: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field ServicePort.spec.ports.nodePort of type int32

I've tryed with various versions of Loadbalancer combinations, even with some which works in other helm charts which I have installed, like:
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 8088
  targetPort: http
  containerPort: 8088
  protocol: TCP
  name: http
  annotations: {}

but same errors again.
Can anyone share solution or give some hints?
Regards

If this is important, kubernetes was deployed with Rancher

I fixed this by adding dummy value in nodePort. In my case I was using the helm chart for Superset: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/superset/superset, and the service template would force a nodePort value when using LoadBalancer.. hence the error.
service:
  type: loadBalancer
  port: 8088
  nodePort:
    http:""

